# HDLBits Dff8p - Reset not working when using a generate loop

Tags: verilog, hdl, flip-flop

I'm trying to solve [this HDLBits question](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Dff8p), and my problem occurs when submitting the following code:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [7:0] d,
    output [7:0] q
);
    
    genvar i;
    generate for(i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1)
        begin: DFF
            dFlipFlop instance_i(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .d(d[i]), .q(q[i]));
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule

module dFlipFlop(input clk, input reset, input d, output q);
    always@(negedge clk) begin
        if(reset) q <= 8'h34;
        else q <= d;
    end
endmodule
```

Submitting this code gives me the hint "Your reset doesn't seem to be working.", and it is an unsuccessful attempt.

This error is fixed by removing the use of the `generate` loop and implementing a single, 8-bit flip flop as follows:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [7:0] d,
    output [7:0] q
);
    
    always@(negedge clk) begin
        if(reset) q <= 8'h34;
        else q <= d;
    end

endmodule
```

Why does the use of a `generate` loop cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the `generate` loop.

The problem is this line:

```
    if(reset) q <= 8'h34;
```

When you declare `output q`, `q` is 1-bit wide, but you attempt to assign an 8-bit value to it (`8'h34`).  This is the same as `8'b0011_0100`.  `q` is always assigned to the LSB of the value, which is 0.  The 7 MSBs are ignored.  This means that all 8 instances of `dFlipFlop` are reset to the same value (0).  The code behaves as though you used this line:

```
    if(reset) q <= 0;
```

When you declare `q` as 8-bit (`output [7:0] q`), you successfully reset the 8-bit `q` to the desired value.

When I run your code on the HDLBits website, I see this warning when I click on the "Show Quartus messages..." link:

> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at top_module.v(19):
> truncated value with size 8 to match size of target (1) File:
> /home/h/work/hdlbits.14193329/top_module.v Line: 19

Comment: Ah didn't think to check what 0x34 looked like in binary, so the question is asking for 3 of the flip-flops to output 1 in the reset state which is why my code is not working.